# Slow and dirty fragments transactions

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have three `fragments` in the same `MainFragmentActivity` lets say: left , right and top fragment. 
The left `fragment` can change, the other ones are fixed. In other to change the left `fragment` for a new one I have this function on MainFragmentActivity

```
public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        hideAllFragments();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.enter);
        fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

The problem is that sometimes the new `Fragment` received in the function has a lot of things to do itself (long arrays list operations) and the screen is showed white for a few seconds.
I am doing something with `AsyncTask` like

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        //progress //show progress
        }

    @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            hideAllFragments();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.enter);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


     @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             //progress dismiss
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);

            }
```

But It does not work.
Any idea about what to do in order to avoid the white screen while the new `fragment` coming in the function is operating?

Comment: Don't async the fragment transaction. Async the slow bit "long arrays list operations" in the slow fragment

Comment: Yes I wish, but is a very dirty code, not mine :(

Comment: That's the solution though :) It's doing too much on the UI thread and nothing you can do is going to change that other than fixing that...

Comment: yes that is true